# FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run the code below using tensorflow,and get the error :

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel
 [[Node: rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel)]]
```

I search the similar error in the website but doesnot work well with my code .

The train.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
q = np.array([[1,2,3,1,4],[2,3,4,1,0],[3,4,1,2,1]])

f = np.ones((3,2,5))
y = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]])
#init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    m = model.Readers_Model(3,0.01,5,5,2,5,5)
    sess.run(m.init_op)
    loss,_ = sess.run([m.input_()],
    {m.question_placeholder:q,m.fact_placeholder:f,
    m.label_placeholder:y,m.dropout_placeholder:0.1})

    print ('loss is %f'%loss)
```

model.py:

```
class Readers_Model(object):

def __init__(self,batch_size,lr,max_q_len,max_f_len,num_doc,hidden_size,vocub_size):
    self.init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    self.embedding_size =   hidden_size   #word embedding
    self.word_embeddings = tf.get_variable('embedding',[self.vocabulary_size, self.embedding_size],
                                           initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0, stddev=1))
    self.label_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(self.batch_size,self.num_class))
    self.fact_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(self.batch_size, self.num_doc, self.max_f_len))
    self.dropout_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    self.question_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(self.batch_size, self.max_q_len),name='question')

def quesiton_encoding_layer(self):
    input = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.word_embeddings, self.question_placeholder)

    gru_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(self.hidden_size)
    output, last_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(gru_cell,
                                 input,
                                 dtype=np.float32,

                                 )

    #shape：[batch_size, GRU_hidden_size]
    '''
    last_state = tf.nn.dropout(last_state, self.dropout_placeholder)
    '''
    last_hidden_unit = last_state[1]

    return output,last_state
```

Just look at the code above,I run the tf.initalize_all_variables() at the beginning of the session and also initialize the tf.variables named embbedding.So what's the reason of error?

Comment: Where do you call `quesiton_encoding_layer`?

Answer (score 0):

The operation `tf.global_variables_initializer()` should be instantiated once all the variables have been created. For example, the following snippet produces a `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
a = tf.Variable(1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(a))
```

Note that in `Readers_Model.__init__` you are instantiating `self.init_op` prior to `self.word_embeddings`, and presumably prior to `gru_cell` as well.